# Ajax call falls into error before running the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ajax call that is falling into error block before even running the controller.
The strange thing is that sometimes(after multiple requests) it does run succesfully but it does not save the cookies in the controller.

I think it could be the ajax call or some permission error. 
AJAX CALL:

```
$('#loginAWGPE').on('click', function () {
    var cpfLogin = $('#cpfValidacao').val().replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
    console.log(cpfLogin);
    console.log(urlOrigem + appPath + "Login/validaCPF");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlOrigem + appPath + "Login/validaCPF",
        datatype: String,
        data: {
            cpf: cpfLogin
        },
        success: function (teste) {
            console.log('dataS: ' + teste);
            if (teste = true) {
                window.location = urlOrigem + appPath + "ProjetoEletrico/Index";
            } else {
                alert('CPF não cadastrado na Agência Virtual!');
            }
        },
        error: function (teste2) {
            console.log('dataE: ' + teste2);
            alert('Erro na execusão');
        }
    });
});
```

-------CONTROLLER:

```
public JsonResult validaCPF(String cpf)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cpf))
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return Json(false);
        }
        WebAPIPArameter id = new WebAPIPArameter();
        id.ParameterName = "id";
        id.ParameterValue = cpf;
        List<WebAPIPArameter> list = new List<WebAPIPArameter>();
        list.Add(id);
        Usuario userInfo = (Usuario)apiClientSistema.GetItem<Usuario>(serviceNameUserInfo, list);
        if (userInfo == null)
        {
            return Json(false);
        }
        else
        {
            CultureInfo cult = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
            String dataStr = userInfo.DTH_ULTIMO_ACESSO.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", cult);
            HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
            cook["cpfCnpj"] = userInfo.NUM_CPF_CNPJ_CLIENTE.ToString();
            cook["nomeCompleto"] = userInfo.NOM_CLIENTE;
            cook["dataAcesso"] = dataStr;
            cook["email"] = userInfo.END_EMAIL;
            cook.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cook);
            //cookie de autenticacao
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                            1,
                                            cpf,  // Id do usuário é muito importante
                                            DateTime.Now,
                                            DateTime.Now.AddHours(4),
                                            true,   // Se você deixar true, o cookie ficará no PC do usuário
                                            "");
            HttpCookie cookieAuth = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookieAuth);
        }
        Response.Redirect("~/ProjetoEletrico/Index");
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant controller code / route information?

Comment: `falling into error block` since you have a console.log of the error, you should see what the error is - we can't

Comment: @John I added the controller

Comment: @bravo It returns only a [object Object] message

Comment: Can you change it to `console.log('dataE: ', teste2);` (comma, not +) so that it doesn't try to convert `teste2` to a string (which is why it's returning "[object Object]")?

Comment: or even `console.log(teste2);`

Comment: @bravo, thank you, I didn't knew that. Here's what I get:     dataE:  {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Comment: ok, so the first argument to `error` is basically *useless* for debugging ... try `error: function (teste2, error, exception) { console.log(error); console.log(exception); }`

Comment: @bravo I did as you explain and I got a empty exception. It gives me nothing and it's driving me crazy. I am not sure if it's the ajax or some configuration at the web.config but I've tried all tags I saw on google.

Comment: `I got a empty exception` what about the **error**

Comment: @bravo another thing i'm thinking is that I depend on the cookie to stay logged but it's not being saved. Yet, sometime it does not even get the cookie point. Sometimes it does.

Comment: @bravo error also empty

Comment: Here the data sending in json object when your type is string.

secondly check the path urlOrigem + appPath + "Login/validaCPF"

Comment: Could be that you've set the data type to datatype and your expected a JSON object. Other than As LDS said check your URL.
The network tab in chrome may also provide some information about the issue.
Good luck.

Comment: try adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` to the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. It was a stupid mistake....
I forgot the "submit" in my form button and I also the ajax call.